# Calling ZipZap's updateEntries method causes a crash in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, archiving, zipzap

I've been trying to create an archive using the ZipZap library (https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap) and to be more specific the 8.0 release. The library is consumed in Swift code.

I've read that when calling:

```
newArchive.updateEntries(archiveItems, error: error)
```

Requires the "archiveItems" to be NSMutableArray and it is defined as such. At this point I tried creating an archive that contains just one directory so the array looks like:

```
var archiveItems = NSMutableArray()
archiveItems.addObject(ZZArchiveEntry(directoryName: "\(archiveName)/"))
```

"newArchive" is created the following way:

```
var newArchive = ZZArchive(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: archivePath), error: error)
```

The error I see is: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1, subcode=0x1001bc998)

And I've also seen: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1, subcode=0x100100998)

In case I do not call the updateEntries method the code does not crash. So my assumption is that the crash happens inside this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it was me not reading the spec as it is written in the example on GitHub.

After a help from Glen Low (pixelglow) the issue was that I am actually trying to create a new file without sending an option to create the file in case it does not exist.

So a massive thanks goes to pixelglow for his help and the great library!

The proper way to call the init when you need to create the file is:

```
var newArchive = ZZArchive(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: archivePath), options: [ZZOpenOptionsCreateIfMissingKey: true], error: &archiveError)
```